# can we change the suffix for queue additional tables in N service Bus

Tags: c#, nservicebus

can we change the suffix for queue additional tables in N service Bus?
I am using sqlserver transport.
I need to change the tables names like Queue.Retries to Queue_Retries

Comment: Why would you want to do this?

Comment: because we have our own table structure and our DBA not allowing me to add dot in table name.

Answer (score 0):

There is no API for changing the algorithm for internal NServiceBus queue naming.

Comment: yes it seems like we can't change the naming of tables.